# What are the alternatives for ABAQUS in generating an *.inp file from a CAD model

Tags: finite-element, simulation, mesh-generation

ABAQUS gives a .inp file (in pre-processing stage) where the information with regard to the preprocessed model is defined, information such as geometry, mesh type, number of elements, boundary conditions, etc. This file is in turn used for the processing part in a solver. I have a solver that takes in .inp files and I would like to know what are the alternatives for ABAQUS in obtaining a .inp file (I don't have access to ABAQUS). I know that Hypermesh gives .inp files too.

What are open-source/free software from which I ca get .inp files? and what are the commercial software such as ABAQUS and Hypermesh?

**Edit**

Some clarification:

I have a topology optimization solver that takes .inp files as input to do topology optimization calculation on them. But I don't have Abaqus to create my .inp files and feed them to my solver. So I am looking for a free tool that can create .inp files for me. I have access to CAD tools such as Catia and Solidworks to create geometries and loading (I assume I can define loading in Solidworks and Catia right?) I just need a free tool to generate .inp files from my CAD files.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need to create *.inp input-files, if you don't have access to ABAQUS? In the case of ABAQUS, the *.inp files are simply text files containing all the relevant information on a simulation case, written in a format that ABAQUS is able to process. So if you don't have ABAQUS, why the need for *.inp files?

Comment: Are you looking for a software that actually create volumetric mesh for you and export volumetric mesh + BCs + etc. as an .inp file? If yes, your best bet is using GMSH.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer , No I have a topology optimization solver that take .inp files as input to do topology optimization calculation on them. But I don't have Abaqus to create my inp files and feed them to my solver. So I am looking for a free tool that can create inp files for me. I have access to CAD tools such as Catia and Solidworks I just need a free tool to generate inp files from my CAD files.

Comment: @Dude Yes, I know and that's the reason why I'm recommending GMSH. It's free and is what you want to convert CAD formats to .inp.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, Thanks I will try it.

Comment: Do you already have a solver? I would suggest that you add which one.

Comment: @nicoguaro, it's an in house solver developped for topology optimization calculation.

Comment: I was wondering why an in-house software has that format, but I bet you didn't program it. I would like to add that Calculix use (pretty much) the same input files as Abaqus.

Comment: @nicoguaro, You guessed right nico, I inherited the solver from a team of colleagues who chose to feed the solver using an .inp file because they had access to Abaques and I don't. So I got two options: either define a new routine where I program a new entry file as an input considering a different format available on an open source software or simply find an open source software that gives me an .inp file. The second option is less expensive in terms of time and energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also recommend using the [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) Python library to convert meshes among many formats: Abaqus, gmsh, Nastran, VTK, etc. With this library you don't necessarily need a meshing software that generates the Abaqus format.

Answer (score 1):

Sandia distributes a CAD/meshing tool called CUBIT that can generate ABAQUS outputs (among numerous other formats). It's free for government use. It's also been rebranded/cross-branded into a commercial tool called Trelis.

Links:
[CUBIT](https://cubit.sandia.gov/), [Trelis](https://www.csimsoft.com/trelis)

Comment: Trelis gives a 30 days trial I think but I'm not sure it helps if OP wants to use it for long time and build on it.

Comment: Also, for CUBIT, from "It's free for government use." you mean it should be used only by national labs' researchers or it needs some sort of proof for showing that you are US citizen?

Comment: Basically, you need to provide some proof of a government contract that's supporting your work (stronger than citizenship, but still pretty wide latitude).