# Gmsh for .inp file

Tags: mesh-generation, gmsh

How do I get an `.inp` file from Gmsh? I need to create a simple geometry and mesh it and define the boundary conditions in Gmsh and export it as an `.inp` file at the end (because I need to use it in a third party solver). I couldn't find much help from the documentation of Gmsh it seems there exists a mesh file format in Gmsh that exits in two flavors: ASCII and binary.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `.inp` is a pretty generic extension. Is there any formal format specification or where is it going to be used?

Comment: @AntonMenshov, I have a solver that gets .inp files created in Abaqus, but I don't have access to Abaqus, so I found out that it is possible to create inp files using gmsh, but I had a look at the documentation of gmsh and I couldn't figure out how to create an .inp file with gmsh. that's the story.

Comment: The place you're most likely to find answers are the gmsh-specific mailing lists.

Comment: @Dude I wanted to write an answer mentioning the `meshio` library, but realized that someone has already posted an answer: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/34456/18289
I can highly recommend that actively maintained Python library.

Answer (score 3):

There are powerful tools for mesh conversion, for example [MeshIO](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio/).
With this open-source tool installed you would only have to type for conversion of msh-to-inp (vice versa for inp-to-msh)

```
meshio convert --input-format gmsh --output-format abaqus inputfile.msh outputfile.inp
```

I tested it on Ubuntu linux (22.04) and Python (3.10.6), it works with both ascii and binary files.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get any suggestion, here are mine:

If you need to get started with gmsh from scratch, take a look at their tutorial section [here](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Tutorial), their [wiki](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/wikis/home) or on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xL2LmDsDLYw).

You can mesh your created geometry and export it as an .inp file. In the gui use: File -> Export -> then select .inp as file format. If you want to use gmsh from the command line look [here](http://onelab.info/pipermail/gmsh/2012/007462.html). For defining boudary conditions take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moose-users/LD5K6sG9bKY). I'm not 100% sure but I don't think you can define boundary conditions as such in gmsh. You'll have to create a Physical Group for that, see [her](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Elementary-entities-vs-physical-groups) in their documentation.

Comment: You could add the explanations instead of just adding links to other websites

Comment: @riyansh.legend   how can we import .inp file into Gmsh? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @YSVSDVXCVXCV According to this [comment](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/847#note_9816) of the owner, there's only a .inp writer and no reader function.